# Problem adding a custom field to Devise while testing with cucumber

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber

I added a `username` field to my Rails app that's using Devise. I did all the necessary steps like adding the field to the views, adding it to the `User` model, migrating my database, etc. Now, when I run through the registration steps manually everything works fine. But as soon as I try to write a feature in Cucumber I get a huge page of errors.

Here's a very short list of the errors I get when running my cucumber feature

```
  Scenario: New user registration with valid info # features/user_access.feature:7
When I sign up as a new user with valid info  # features/step_definitions/user_access_steps.rb:5
  undefined method `username' for #<User:0x00000102f7dcf0> (ActionView::Template::Error)
  /Users/Daniel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136@Flow1/gems/activemodel-3.0.3/lib/active_model/attribute_methods.rb:364:in `method_missing'
  /Users/Daniel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136@Flow1/gems/activerecord-3.0.3/lib/active_record/attribute_methods.rb:46:in `method_missing'
  /Users/Daniel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136@Flow1/gems/actionpack-3.0.3/lib/action_view/helpers/form_helper.rb:1019:in `value_before_type_cast'
  /Users/Daniel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136@Flow1/gems/actionpack-3.0.3/lib/action_view/helpers/form_helper.rb:1007:in `value_before_type_cast'
  /Users/Daniel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136@Flow1/gems/actionpack-3.0.3/lib/action_view/helpers/form_helper.rb:915:in `block in to_input_field_tag'
  /Users/Daniel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136@Flow1/gems/actionpack-3.0.3/lib/action_view/helpers/form_helper.rb:915:in `fetch'
```

I have isolated the error to my Devise view. For some reason cucumber doesn't like the following lines

```
<%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
<%= devise_error_messages! % >

<p><%= f.label :username %><br />
<%= f.text_field :username %></p>
```

For some reason cucumber wont play nice with the :username label and text_field. All I am doing in my cucumber steps is going to the registration page and trying to fill in `username` with a name.

Any idea what is causing this error and how to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you updated the test database? `rake db:test:prepare`

Comment: btw, did you realize it was the db just by looking at the errors?